# How to get query SELECT in MySQL log using regex

Tags: python, mysql, regex, python-3.x, parsing

I want to parse mysql log using regex in python. But the result is not coming out and there's no error in there. I want to get timestamp and only SELECT query. This is the example of the log:

```
190410  7:55:29 32168488 Connect    cis_production@172.21.7.4 on cis_production
    32168488 Query  SET NAMES 'utf8'
    32168488 Query  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `sysx_user`
    32168488 Query  SELECT *
FROM information_schema.referential_constraints AS rc
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu ON
kcu.constraint_schema = rc.constraint_schema AND
kcu.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name
WHERE rc.constraint_schema = database() AND kcu.table_schema = database()
AND rc.table_name = 'sysx_user' AND kcu.table_name = 'sysx_user'
    32168488 Query  SELECT * FROM `dimx_dim` WHERE user_id = 3060
```

Here is the regex that i've already tried:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(\d{6}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [0-9]{8}) (.*?)(?=\d{8} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [0-9]{8} |$)', re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

I expect to get only the SELECT log. Not the entire log. This is expected result:

```
[("190410  7:55:29 32168488 Connect cis_production@172.21.7.4 on",
  "SELECT *FROM information_schema.referential_constraints AS rc JOIN 
   information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu ON kcu.constraint_schema = 
   rc.constraint_schema AND kcu.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name WHERE 
   rc.constraint_schema = database() AND kcu.table_schema = database() AND 
   rc.table_name = 'sysx_user' AND kcu.table_name = 'sysx_user'",
   " SELECT * FROM `dimx_dim` WHERE user_id = 3060")]
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't there be a table in the database that stores user ids, the query id, and the actual query themselves? most modern databases have this feature, wouldn't it be prudent to check for that first and use that?

Comment: yes, but in this case i only want to parse the query log and not interact to the database directly. I want to get the SELECT query log for each execution time.

Comment: is querying the database expensive or something? you can give it a time range and extract all the queries from the database. unless I am misunderstanding you are making your task more difficult than it should be given there is a cleaner way to do this without the need for regex

Comment: @aws_apprentice I'm sorry for unclear question. I've updated my question.

Comment: the question is clear, but you have not answered my question, why are you doing this instead of getting it from the database? as I have stated if you have a cleaner more reliable way to obtain the query why are you going this route?

Comment: because i only have the log file data, not the database. all that i can do is only process the log file.

Comment: Regex probably isn't going to be a good solution here unless you have a reliable delimiter.  You might be able to use other keywords `SELECT` as your delimiter, but that doesn't mean that what gets captured between them will ll be part of the SELECT statement especially if this is a log file ;/

Comment: Note that the hour is sometimes only 1 digit.

Answer (score 0):

|^()()()()/usr/sbin/mariadbd,.*$|^()()()()Tcp port:.*$|()()()()Time.*Argument$|^(\d{6} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(\d+) (\w+)\t(.++)|^()\t\t\s+(?=\d)(\d+) (Query|Connect)\t([[:ascii:]]+)(?=\n\t\t)|()^\t\t\s+(?=\d)(\d+) (Quit)\s*$

The expression need gUm as Regex Option

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).